# NASM x86 Segfault

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

The following code is meant to find the sum of all numbers less than 1000 that are multiples of 3 or 5. (Project Euler first problem).

However, it is giving a segmentation fault when I execute it.
I have a feeling it may have something to do with after returning from my check function, I pop ebx off the stack before adding 8 to esp to restore the stack frame. Is this true and if so what can I do to fix it?

```
section .data
section .text
msg: db "%d", 0

global main
extern printf

main:

mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 0
;MAINLOOP
loopstart:
    inc ebx         
    cmp ebx, 999        ;check if we are done
    je done         ;if we are, exit
    push 3
    push ebx        ;otherwise, check if our number is a multiple of 3
    call check
    pop ebx
    add esp, 8          ;fix stack pointer
    cmp eax, 1      ;if it is a multiple, add it to our sum
    je true
    push 5
    push ebx
    call check      ;otherwise check if multiple of 5
    pop ebx
    add esp, 8
    cmp eax, 1
    je true         ;if it is, add it to our sum
    jmp loopstart

true:
    add ecx, ebx
    jmp loopstart

done:
    push ecx
    push msg
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    ret


check:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+8]    
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    mov edx, 0
    div ebx

    cmp edx, 0
    je multiple
    mov eax, 0

    pop ebp
    mov esp, ebp
    ret

    multiple:
        mov eax, 1

        pop ebp
        mov esp, ebp
        ret
```

Comment: just realised that when I call functions, my ecx register is also being destroyed. is this what is causing the segfault?

Comment: I don't think so. Ecx is only used as a (safe) parameter to printf. You should just see garbage printed because of that error. BTW. What debugger you are using? (GDB has stepi and nexti to step through machine instructions)

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the problem
The error was in my check function, I was using

```
pop ebp
mov esp, ebp
```

which should have been

```
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

I believe there were also some other errors with restoring stack frame etc.
Here is the complete working code:

```
section .data
section .text
msg: db "%d", 0
global main
extern printf

main:

mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, 0

loopstart:

inc ebx
cmp ebx, 1000
je done
push ecx
push ebx
push 3
call check
add esp, 4
pop ebx
pop ecx
cmp eax, 1
je true
push ecx
push ebx
push 5
call check
add esp, 4
pop ebx
pop ecx
cmp eax, 1
je true
jmp loopstart

true:
add ecx, ebx
jmp loopstart

done:
push ecx
push msg
call printf
add esp, 8
ret

check:

    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [ebp+12]   
    mov ebx, [ebp+8]
    mov edx, 0
    div ebx

    cmp edx, 0
    je multiple
    mov eax, 0

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret

    multiple:
        mov eax, 1
        mov esp, ebp
        pop ebp
        ret
```